# Calculating percentage change over a range of 5 cells where a different two will be populated on each row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 5 columns for 5 consecutive years.

I need to calculate the percentage change between the first value present across the column range and the second value present. The other three columns will be blank.

In the attached picture Z2 would calculate the percentage change for V2 to Y2 but for Z4 it would calculate the percentage change between U4 and Y4.

I would like to find the percentage difference between the first value in the row and the last value in the row.

Column Setup:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: So you want the %-difference between the **first** value in the row and the **last** value in the row ??

Answer (score 0):

In **Z2** enter the **Array Formula**:

```
=(-INDEX(U2:Y2,MATCH(TRUE,U2:Y2<>0,0))+LOOKUP(2,1/(U2:Y2>0),U2:Y2))/INDEX(U2:Y2,MATCH(TRUE,U2:Y2<>0,0))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You can use a *MUCH* simpler formula if the %-change is never negative!